# Cuando actualizo la cantidad de un producto en mi carrito de compras, si me llegué a desplazar hacía abajo, me lleva al comienzo de RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, recyclerview

La aplicación en sí funciona, ya que cuando aumento la cantidad de producto, también me muestra el precio total en la actividad. Sin embargo, es molesto que vuelva al inicio de Recyclerview cuando aumenta la cantidad de producto. Quisiera poder aumentar o disminuir la cantidad de un producto y que todo se actualice pero que me mantenga en la misma posición del recyclerview

Este es mi Adapter

public class RecyclerCarritoAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerCarritoAdapter.ViewHolder> {

```
private List<CarritoModel> model;
private CarritoActivity carritoContext;

private CompositeDisposable compositeDisposable;

public void onStop() {
    compositeDisposable.clear();
}

public RecyclerCarritoAdapter(CarritoActivity carritoContext, List<CarritoModel> model) {
    this.carritoContext = carritoContext;
    this.model = model;
    compositeDisposable = new CompositeDisposable();
}

@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(carritoContext);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.recycler_view_carrito, parent, false);

    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    String imagen = model.get(position).image;
    Picasso.get().load(imagen).placeholder(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background).error(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
            .fit()
            .centerCrop()
            .into(holder.image);

    holder.txt_amount.setNumber(String.valueOf(model.get(position).amount));
    holder.txtName.setText(model.get(position).name);
    holder.txtPrice.setText(new StringBuilder("$").append(model.get(position).price));
    final int cantidad = Integer.parseInt(holder.txt_amount.getNumber());
    double price = model.get(position).price;
    double total = price * cantidad;
    holder.txtTotalPrice.setText(String.valueOf((double)Math.round(total * 100d) / 100d)); //Utilizo la clase "Math" para redondear a sólo dos decimales.
    holder.txtCantidad.setText(holder.txt_amount.getNumber());

    //Autoguardar el item cuando el usuario cambie la cantidad del producto
    holder.txt_amount.setOnValueChangeListener(new ElegantNumberButton.OnValueChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onValueChange(ElegantNumberButton view, int oldValue, int newValue) {
            final CarritoModel carritoModel = model.get(position);
            carritoModel.amount = newValue;

            Common.cartRepository.updateCart(carritoModel);

            //Obtenemos el precio total del pedido y lo añadimos al TextView del CarritoFragment
            compositeDisposable.add(
                    Common.cartRepository.sumPrice()
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .subscribe(new Consumer<Long>() {
                        @Override
                        public void accept(Long mLong) throws Exception {
                                carritoContext.txtTotalPrice.setText(String.valueOf(Math.round(mLong * 100d) / 100d));
                        }
                    })
            );
        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return model.size();
}


public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    TextView txtName;
    TextView txtPrice;
    TextView txtCantidad;
    ElegantNumberButton txt_amount;
    TextView txtTotalPrice;
    ImageView image;

    public RelativeLayout view_background;
    public LinearLayout view_foreground;

    public ViewHolder(@NonNull final View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        txtName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtTitleCarrito);
        txtPrice = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtPrecio);
        txtCantidad = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtCantidad);
        txt_amount = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_amountCarrito);
        txtTotalPrice = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtPrecioTotal);
        image = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivCarrito);

        view_background = itemView.findViewById(R.id.view_background);
        view_foreground = itemView.findViewById(R.id.view_foreground);
    }
}

public void removeItem(int position) {
    model.remove(position);
    notifyItemRemoved(position);
}

public void restoreItem(CarritoModel item, int position) {
    model.add(position, item);
    notifyItemInserted(position);
}
```

}

Esta es mi Activity:

public class CarritoActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements RecyclerItemTouchHelperListener {

```
private RecyclerView recyclerCarrito;
private Button btnContinuarCompra;
public TextView txtTotalPrice;
private TextView txtProductosCount;

//Elementos para la animación de carga
private Dialog mDialogLoading;
private LottieAnimationView mAnimationLoading;

private List<CarritoModel> carritoList = new ArrayList<>();

private CompositeDisposable compositeDisposable;

private RecyclerCarritoAdapter carritoAdapter;

private AuthProvider mAuthProvider;
private ClientBookingProvider mClientBookingProvider;

private RelativeLayout rootLayout;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_carrito);

    mAuthProvider = new AuthProvider();
    mClientBookingProvider = new ClientBookingProvider();

    mDialogLoading = new Dialog(this);
    mDialogLoading.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_carga);
    mAnimationLoading = mDialogLoading.findViewById(R.id.animationLoading);
    mDialogLoading.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));

    // ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Carrito de compras"); //Para cambiar el nombre al Toolbar

    txtProductosCount = findViewById(R.id.txtProductos);

    compositeDisposable = new CompositeDisposable();

    recyclerCarrito = findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewCarrito);
    recyclerCarrito.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    recyclerCarrito.setHasFixedSize(true);

    ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback simpleCallback = new RecyclerItemTouchHelper(0, ItemTouchHelper.LEFT, this);
    new ItemTouchHelper(simpleCallback).attachToRecyclerView(recyclerCarrito);

    txtTotalPrice = findViewById(R.id.txtFinalPrice);
    btnContinuarCompra = findViewById(R.id.btn_continuarCompra);
    btnContinuarCompra.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mDialogLoading.show();
            continuarCompra();
        }
    });

    rootLayout = findViewById(R.id.rootLayout);

    cargarCarrito();
}

private void continuarCompra() {
    //Validaremos si el carrito está vacío.
    compositeDisposable.add(
            Common.cartRepository.getAllCarts()
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .subscribe(new Consumer<List<CarritoModel>>() {
                        @Override
                        public void accept(List<CarritoModel> carritoModels) throws Exception {
                            if (!carritoModels.isEmpty()) { //Si el carrito NO está vacío...
                                //Validaremos si no hay un pedido en en proceso del mismo Cliente.
                                mClientBookingProvider.getClientBooking()
                                        .child(mAuthProvider.getId())
                                        .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                                                if (snapshot.exists()) { //Si ya hay un pedido en camino...
                                                    Toast.makeText(CarritoActivity.this, "Tienes un pedido en camino, sólo puedes realizar un pedido al mismo tiempo", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                                    mDialogLoading.dismiss();
                                                } else { //Si NO hay ningún pedido en camino...
                                                    Intent intent = new Intent(CarritoActivity.this, MapClientActivity.class);
                                                    startActivity(intent);
                                                    mDialogLoading.dismiss();
                                                }
                                            }
                                            @Override
                                            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                                            }
                                        });
                            } else { //Si el carrito ESTÁ VACÍO...
                                Toast.makeText(CarritoActivity.this, "Debes agregar al menos un producto para continuar.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                mDialogLoading.dismiss(); //Lo ocultaremos si el carrito está vacío.
                            }
                        }
                    })
    );
}

private void cargarCarrito() {
    compositeDisposable.add(
            Common.cartRepository.getAllCarts()
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .subscribe(new Consumer<List<CarritoModel>>() {
                        @Override
                        public void accept(List<CarritoModel> carritoModels) throws Exception {
                            displayCarrito(carritoModels);
                            displayFinalPrice(carritoModels);
                            //Pongo el número de productos en el carrito:
                            txtProductosCount.setText("Productos (" + String.valueOf(Common.cartRepository.countCartItems() + ")"));
                        }
                    })
    );
}

private void displayFinalPrice(List<CarritoModel> carritoModels) {
    double total = 0;
    for (CarritoModel productos : carritoModels)
        total += (productos.price) * (productos.amount);
    Locale locale = new Locale("es", "MX");
    NumberFormat fmt = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(locale);

    txtTotalPrice.setText(fmt.format(total));
    //txtTotalPrice.setText(new StringBuilder("$").append(fmt.format(total)));
}

private void displayCarrito(List<CarritoModel> carritoModels) {
    carritoList = carritoModels;
    carritoAdapter = new RecyclerCarritoAdapter(CarritoActivity.this, carritoModels);
    recyclerCarrito.setAdapter(carritoAdapter);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    compositeDisposable.clear();
    if (carritoAdapter != null) {
        carritoAdapter.onStop();
    }
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    compositeDisposable.clear();
    super.onStop();
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    cargarCarrito();
}

public void onSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction, int position) {
    if (viewHolder instanceof RecyclerCarritoAdapter.ViewHolder) {
        String name = carritoList.get(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()).name;

        final CarritoModel deletedItem = carritoList.get(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
        final int deletedIndex = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();

        //Delete item from adapter
        carritoAdapter.removeItem(deletedIndex);
        //Delete item from Room Database
        Common.cartRepository.deleteCartItem(deletedItem);

        Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(rootLayout, new StringBuilder(name).append("  eliminado del carrito").toString(),
                Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
        snackbar.setAction("Deshacer", new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                carritoAdapter.restoreItem(deletedItem, deletedIndex);
                Common.cartRepository.insertToCart(deletedItem);
                //Actualizamos el toolbar (Lo hago para apreciar que se ha agregado un producto al carrito)
                CarritoActivity.this.invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        });
        snackbar.setActionTextColor(Color.parseColor("#7fb73d"));
        snackbar.show();
        //Actualizamos el toolbar (Lo hago para apreciar que se ha agregado un producto al carrito)
        CarritoActivity.this.invalidateOptionsMenu();
    }
}
```

}